# Style form field control

Tags: visual-web-part, branding

I have created a visual webpart. In that I created a SharePoint form field control instead of asp.net textbox.

I am not able to apply styles to this control and it's not looking good in the form. How can I style this control?

```
<sharepoint:FormField ID="formfield1" runat="server" ControlMode="New" OnInit="listitems_Init" ListId="ecaf0841-5628-4fe5-9126-dccb79090d91"></sharepoint:FormField>
```

If I give `css class="class1"` it is not affecting and also it is disabled from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

CssClass should be one word not splitted. If that doesn't work try this:

Wrap your control in a div or span, then apply your CSS.

```
<span class="mycontrol">
 <SharePoint:FormField CssClass="mytextbox" ID="FormField1"..... </SharePoint:FormField>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.mycontrol input[type="text"] // change input type based on your control
{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me, but its so annoying I can't assign my css through `CssClass`, I have to wrap the sharepoint control in some other html css, then assign it through that. Lame.